# module 'firebase_admob' not found

Tags: flutter, firebase-admob

Trying to add firebase_admob in Flutter project.

First of all I created Firebase project and then 2 apps in that project (Android and iOS).

Executed all steps (including google-services.json/GoogleService-Info.plist and appropriate source code)

In pubspec.yaml just have these dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_admob: ^0.10.0+2
```

Then used this module to add admob functionality:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob/install

When I run this project on Android everything is fine. Test ad banner is shown.

Then trying to run the same repository on mac (command: flutter run). And receive following error:

```
admin@Mac-Admin firebase_admob_test % flutter run
Running "flutter pub get" in firebase_admob_test...                 2.4s
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
 
Running pod install...                                              6.1s
flutter: BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.loaded                         
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         4.9s
Xcode build done.                                           57.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/admin/Projects/firebase_admob_test/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistra
    nt.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'firebase_admob' not found
    @import firebase_admob;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly
    because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select
    a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project
    'Runner')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'Pods-Runner' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.

Source code may be found here
https://github.com/vetalitet/firebase_admob_test

Before asking here I tried to find a solution, but nothing helped. This module is still not visible.
And because I'm new in iOS development, I don't know how to continue investigate this issue.
Maybe you may advice some way to go.

Comment: this lib is deprecated you can replace it by https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

Comment: does this error only exists with this package? could your try to replace  the firebase_admob package with cloud_firestore.